# Why in Python a large chain of normal imports (without cycles) causes a Recursion Error?

Tags: python, python-import

I was testing the limits of importing in Python, I have read that Python does not have limits on import stack system, but I am noticing an issue in one of my projects when the stack is too high. I have read threads about the issue but literally 99% of them are just people having infinite recursion issues.

So I built this small automatic-generation chain of imports. This file creates 300 files where the n-th file calls the file n+1. First file uses a function f that is defined in the 300th file. There is no cycle, last file does not have any imports at all.

Executing the first file gives the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

This error gets solved if I call `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)`, but I don't want to solve this, I want to know why this happens in the first place because I have a similar-but-not-quite-this error in a different project that does not get solved with the setrecursionlimit call.

The things I don't understand are (I add what I think is happening in parenthesis, but I haven't found anything online about this):

1. Why do I get a recursion error if the issue is with imports? (I assume imports are just a call function, and it triggers recursion depth because of the way it internally detects recursion depth in normal functions?)
2. Why is the recursion limit set to 1000 by default, but I'm getting the error at file number 143? (I assume the import function adds 7 layers of recursion on each call, so it explodes at 1000/7?)
3. What's the logic of "Python only has limit for imports for what your RAM allows" when it seems that importing too much in chain also has limits? I understand this limit is not reasonable to reach in normal processes, but are there other limits like this one?

For completion, this is the chain builder script:

```
PREFIX_FOR_TEST_FILES = 'testFile'

def getNameOfFileByNumber(numberOfFile):
    return '{}{}'.format(PREFIX_FOR_TEST_FILES, str(numberOfFile))

def getTextForMiddleFiles(numberOfFile: int) -> str:
    return 'from {} import f'.format(getNameOfFileByNumber(numberOfFile+1))

def getDefinitionOfFForFinalFile() -> str:
    return 'def f(n):return 2*n'

def getFirstFileDefinition() -> str:
    return 'from {}2 import f;print(f(1))'.format(PREFIX_FOR_TEST_FILES)

def createFileWithNameAndWriteContent(nameOfFile, content):
    f = open(nameOfFile + '.py', "w+")
    f.write(content)
    f.close()

numberOfFilesForTest = 300
createFileWithNameAndWriteContent(getNameOfFileByNumber(1), getFirstFileDefinition())
for i in range(2, numberOfFilesForTest):
    createFileWithNameAndWriteContent(getNameOfFileByNumber(i), getTextForMiddleFiles(i))
createFileWithNameAndWriteContent(getNameOfFileByNumber(numberOfFilesForTest), getDefinitionOfFForFinalFile())
```

Comment: The "recursion limit" is really a stack depth limit. It's just called that because recursion is by far the most common reason to hit the limit.

Comment: @user2357112 That makes sense. Anything I can do to solve this issue without inlining my imports?

Comment: You can temporarily increase the limit, and change it back after the last import.

Comment: Each nesting of imports increases the stack depth. You can rearrange your .py source files so that imports are not nested. Alternatively you can explicitly import first. For example, if you have `import a`, and a.py has `import b`, then you can write `import b, a` instead of `import a`. This is called topological sort. The `import b` within a.py will be a no-op.

Comment: @pts The issue is that the project where I have this happening does not have weird nesting imports, they are quite normal. There are simply a lot of them because of its structure and because of using third parties like pyarmor. So I can't easily restructure it, and setrecursionlimit does not solve it. But if I inline the last import (or any of the middle ones), it works. So I think I must be missing something about how imports work, and why all my questions here. Is there anything else besides recursion limit that would cause this?

Comment: @pts You shouldn't generally need to know what modules `a.py` depends on when you import from it.

Comment: "Python only has limit for imports for what your RAM allows" refers to the total number of modules you can import, not nested imports. I.e. if you import too much you could potentially run out of memory loading all of them.

Comment: @AnilCh: I think what you are observing can be caused by the stack depth limit. (Verify it by increasing the stack depth limit to 10**6 before the imports, and observing that the imports succeed.) If you have contrary evidence, share it in your question.

Comment: Maybe only one or two of your imports are problematic, everything else works fine with the default low stack depth. In that case, refactor the imports (e.g. with topological sort) only in those .py source files.

Comment: @pts I understand that it's too much asking about something I'm not showing, but I haven't been able to reproduce the issue outside the project and I can't share the project. The stack depth has been increased and it does not help. Inlining the last import makes it work. Maybe it's just a bug with pyarmor, I don't know. Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: @Barmar Memory usage is normal, pretty low.

Comment: I never said you were running into that. I was answering your third question. In modern systems it's practically impossible to reach that memory limit.

Comment: Show us your imports before (doesn't work) and after (works) inlining.

Comment: @pts The issue appears in a very normal import. "from X file import Y". In X file there is only Y class and an import to abc. When built with pyarmor, it fails with an error in the import. Inlining the import OR removing any parent import from the chain, it works even with pyarmor. So it's not this single import the problem, it must be related with the chain + pyarmor. However, setrecursionlimit does not solve it, for some reason.

Comment: You may want to debug this further by removing all other imports. If it still breaks, then it's very easy to reproduce, and you may want to report this as a bug to the pyarmor developers.